# CSS property 'cursor' not working with :host selector

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, lit-element

I'm trying to figure out how to apply the property **`cursor`** when using **`:host`** selector.

Others properties are correctly applied, but not `cursor`.

```
:host([disabled]) {
    color: #626878;
    background-color: #C0C4CB;  
    cursor: not-allowed!important;  
}
```

`:host` refer to a **web component** made with LitElement.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runs fine:

```js
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() { // so attributes can be queried
      this
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
        .innerHTML = `<style>
                         :host {
                           display:    inline-block;
                         }
                         :host([disabled]) {
                           cursor:     not-allowed !important;
                           background: pink        !important;
                           color:      grey        !important;
                         }
                     </style>
                     <h1>&lt;my-element 
                         ${this.hasAttribute("disabled")?"disabled":""}></h1>`;
    }
  })
```

```html
<style>
  my-element{
    cursor:     pointer;
    background: lightgreen;
    color:      green;
  }
</style>

<my-element></my-element>
<my-element disabled></my-element>
```

#### Requires `!important`

**From https://web.dev/shadowdom-v1/**

> One gotcha with :host is that rules in the parent page have higher
> specificity than :host rules defined in the element. That is, outside
> styles win. This allows users to override your top-level styling from
> the outside. Also, :host only works in the context of a shadow root,
> so you can't use it outside of shadow DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for the explaination